# PyAudiere alternatives for Mac OSX?

Tags: python, audio, core-audio, low-latency

I am working on a music application in Python. I am using [PyAudiere](http://pyaudiere.org/) for low-latency audio playback, but I found that it is not very easy to get working on Mac OSX (I haven't managed to compile it given the instructions, I get the message `DeviceFrame.cpp:60: error: call of overloaded ‘wxString(const char*)’ is ambiguous`). Is there another good Python audio framework which works on Mac? I need the ability to adjust pitch and volume dynamically, and low latency; PyPy compatibility would be good, but not essential.

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to use our open-source bindings to OpenAL (MIT-style license).  We use them quite extensively on Mac and Windows: http://hg.techgame.net/TG/ext/openAL/

It was created as an internal project, so there is no documentation.  It's a fairly simple wrapper over the OpenAL API to make it somewhat object oriented.

Comment: Hmm. I had to do a bit of work to get it to import, and now it is saying: `ImportError: No module named TG.kvObserving`. What methods does it need KVObject for?

Comment: @user677624 — Sorry for the getting started troubles.  The repository is full of our internally used open source, and I have never carved out the time to release it properly.  TG.kvObserving and TG.metaObserving are my standardized way to publish/subscribe attributes.  In openAL, they are used to synthesize events from certain state transitions.  You can find it from http://hg.techgame.net/TG/